# Orthogonal complex matrices: polar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, matrices, lie-groups

Is there a decomposition of $SL_n(\mathbb C)$ as a product of $O_n(\mathbb C)\times Sym_n(\mathbb C)$ ? 
I mean is there a result as the polar decomposition but with orthogonal (not unitary)?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is known as the [algebraic polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Other_decompositions) of a matrix.  It is apparently equivalent to the similarity of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ (when $A$ is an arbitrary complex matrix).

For a reference, see Choudhury & Horn 1987, pp. 219-225.

Comment: But I think there is a pb, because if $SL_n\cong SO_n\times Sym_n$ they must have the same fondamental group, which is not the case!! $SL_n$ is simply connected, but $SO_n$ is not.

Comment: It's not a decomposition in the sense of the Cartesian product of spaces. However, like the polar decomposition of $\Bbb R^n$, it is a Cartan decomposition.